# Iterating over a multi-level object?

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

I have a multi-level object that has dynamic names and goes about 2 levels deep. I came up with a solution that works if there is only one dynamic-object, however I am having trouble writing the loop for multiples. Here are the basics.

My object looks like this:

```
{ 
  dynamic_name1: { 
    mods: [ 
      [Object], [Object] 
    ] 
  }, 

  dynamic_name2: { 
    mods: [ 
      [Object], [Object]
    ] 
   }, 

  dynamic_name3: { 
    mods: [ 
      [Object], [Object]
    ] 
  } 
}
```

Basically, I want to iterate over this object, and get the objects from within each of the respective `mods` arrays, then push them to a different array.

I am getting this object, with the variable `container`, then structure like so:

```
const [objectKeys] = Object.keys(container);
const modsList = container[objectKeys].mods;
```

This solution works really well because then I just add it to my new array like this:

```
const myMods = [...modsList]
```

However, this whole functionality seems to break when I try to loop it. here's what I have so far:

```
for (j = 0; j < container.length; j++){
  const [objectKeys] = Object.keys(container);
}
```

but when trying to log `[objectKeys]` I get undefined. Any idea how I could do this?

Comment: @Taki Here is a snippet: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/568bpd42/).

Comment: thnx, i just misread your post,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get all the mods reducing a map over your dynamic sub-objects, something like:

```
const container = { 
  dynamic_name1: { 
    mods: [ 
      1, 2
    ] 
  }, 

  dynamic_name2: { 
    mods: [ 
      3, 4
    ] 
   }, 

  dynamic_name3: { 
    mods: [ 
      5, 6
    ] 
  } 
}

const mods = Object.values(container)
                   .map(sub => sub.mods)
                   .reduce(
                     (result, mods) => [...result, ...mods],
                     []
                   )

console.log(mods)
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This way you can loop at the end.

Comment: This worked really well for what I was trying to do, thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Object.values(/*...*/).reduce((result, { mods }) => [...result, ...mods], []);

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, below function should accept an object and return an array with all 2nd level mods

```
function extractMods(container) {
    return Object.keys(container).reduce((r, c) => [...r, ...container[c].mods], [])
}
```

Call it like below

```
extractMods({
    a: {
        mods: [0,1,2,3,4]
    },
    b: {
        mods: [5,6,7,8,9]
    },
    c: {
        mods: [10,11,12,13,14]
    },
})
```

It will return

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Comment: [discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @Taki, Removed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Good example of why I dislike dynamic property names. An array consisting of: `[{"name":"dynamic_name1","mods":[{},{}]},{"name":"dynamic_name2","mods":[{},{}]}]` gives you easy loops.

But to help with the issue, `Object.keys()` has some siblings: Object.entries() and Object.values() .

```js
const data = { 
  dynamic_name1: { 
    mods: [ 
      { id: 1 },
      { id: 2}
    ] 
  }, 

  dynamic_name2: { 
    mods: [ 
      { id: 3 },
      { id: 4 }
    ] 
   }, 

  dynamic_name3: { 
    mods: [ 
      { id: 5 },
      { id: 6 }
    ] 
  } 
};

const modsList = Object.values( data ).flatMap( entry => entry.mods );

console.log( modsList );
```

If your browser does not support flatMap() yet, you can do the same with a map() or reduce().

Comment: Yeah I'm personally not a fan of dynamic obj. names,  but I'm getting this data with a page scrape, so I have to plan ahead that the mods are going to be in dynamic containers

Comment: If I would need to do alot of operations often, so not only getting one property once, I found it's more efficient to just bite the bullet and loop to reformat the data immediately after scraping it. You lose initial time, but make up for it later on compared to using nested Object.keys/values/entries() in all the transformations happening to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = {
    dynamic_name1: { mods: [{x:1}, {x:2}] },
    dynamic_name2: { mods: [{x:3}, {x:4}] },
    dynamic_name3: { mods: [{x:5}, {x:6}] }
}

let result = Object.values(obj).reduce((a, b) => (a.push(...b.mods), a), []);
console.log( result )
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with

```
for (j = 0; j < container.length; j++){
  const [objectKeys] = Object.keys(container);
}
```

is that `container.length` is undefined, therefore, there's zero iterations and `objectKeys` is never assigned.

Use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the resulting array to return the `mods`, then [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) it with`depth` of `2` :

```js
const container = {
  dynamic_name1: {
    mods: [
      [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  },

  dynamic_name2: {
    mods: [
      [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  },

  dynamic_name3: {
    mods: [
      [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  }
}

const myMods = Object.values(container).map(e => e.mods).flat(2);

console.log(myMods);
```